Why following different lenient approaches is wicked?
Tosefta Yevamot.1.13

"לעולם הלכה כדברי בית הלל,
הרוצה להחמיר על עצמו לנהוג כדברי בית שמיי וכדברי בית הלל,
על זה נאמ' הכסיל בחשך ילך,
התופס קולי בית שמיי וקולי בית הלל רשע,
אלא אם כדברי בית שמיי כקוליהן וכחומריהון,
אם כדברי בית הלל כקוליהון וכחומריהון."


"Whoever wishes to be stringent upon themselves and follow the rulings of both the House of Shammai and the House of Hillel, it is said: 'The fool walks in darkness.'
The one who adopts the lenient rulings of the House of Shammai and the lenient rulings of the House of Hillel is wicked."

Both seem counterintuitive: following all the stringencies sounds pious, and since the leniences of both houses are strict Halachic rulings believed to descend from the Living God, following all of them can not be considered wicked.
Why does the Tosefta consider it foolish to follow the stringencies of both, and why does it call one who picks the leniencies as wicked?

It's talking about a case where the same stringency becomes a leniency somewhere else, and vice versa (Eruvin 7a)

Doesn't halacha say you are supposed to follow Bet Hillel?

@MauriceMizrahi A keen observation. It appears that the idea of Halachic resolution or a ruling Halacha was adopted much later toward the end of Babylonian Talmud, so the opening phrase "לעולם הלכה כדברי בית הלל" is more of a political statement (since they eventually usurped the rulership) and not Halachic, as we observe disagreements for hundreds of years.

There is a principle of דרך ישרה - straight path that a person should follow (mishna Avos 2:1). Every system of halacha is based on it. For example, when commenting on the דירשו edition of Mishnah Berurah, my rosh yeshivah praised that it is considered balanced. Straight path is important, because it is considered as a way of peace, RaDaK on Psalms 119:165 and many others. Following leniencies, according to the mishnah is tiferes for oneself, following stringencies is tiferes to Hashem and other people - both may give a wrong impression.
Finally, to answer your specific question about wickedness of leniencies, that's due Avos 5:10: [One that says:] “mine is mine, and yours is mine” is a wicked person. In this case, a lenient person is only concerned about own tiferes. While the word tiferes is translated as honor in Sefaria, it's meaning is glory, splendor, as in the description of Aharon's vestments. I.e. it has connection to spiritual reward.

Thank you. What do you mean by "Every system of halacha", how many are there?

@AlBerko in your question it was Beis Hillel vs. Beis Shammai; in learning Gemara with commentary, it is Rashi vs. Tosafos; nowadays sefardi vs. ashkenazi, etc. In general every posek has his definition of straight path, and follows a specific logic, as Shtika K'hodaa tried to argue.

@AlBerko i added a final point to fully answer your question.

I don't get how following fully Halachic leniences makes it to "mine is mine, and yours is mine". And I'm not familiar with the term tifferes, is that a Kabbalistic term?

@AlBerko from the point of observance tiferes contained in the mitzvah is only for the lenient. It's not kabbala, but think of spiritual benefit.

@AlBerko some translate tiferes as honor, but it's not quite. Need to check commentary on Avos 2:1.

I still don't get it, any lenient approach is backed by a knowledgeable rabbi. In times when there's no single authority, why lenient is evil?

@AlBerko you are redefining your question. Given extenuating circumstances a lenient approach can be derekh yeshara. Your original question is when it it is ɓeing strict and lenient has very comparable utility cost.

IDK: "Why does the Tosefta consider it foolish to follow the stringencies of both, and why does it call one who picks the leniencies as wicked?"

@AlBerko During a war or trying times performance of mitzvos is suspended but those who do merit big rewards (I cannot find the exact mishna wording). Recall what MIriam said to Amram her father when he divorced Yocheved, she did not call him a rasha. She asked to go beyond the letter of law.

Halacha needs to be consistent and not just strict or lenient. It's therefore advisable to follow a sheeta which can be directed by a rav. Not doing so can lead to unintentional consequences. An example given in a halacha shiur I was attending a woman who wanted to be very strict about passover and only used schmaltz for cooking but then accidentally cooked her fish in it as well. Another example being machmir with brachos could Gd for id lead to a bracha levatala.
Being lenient is also not desirable as practically not all lenient approaches are truly acceptable in normal situations even if they might be relied in in a case of a big loss or emergency. Additionally as it says in pirke avos 2:12, "And all your deeds should be for the sake of Heaven." Always doing was is easiest or most comfortable while technically within the realm of halacha is self serving and not for the sake of heaven.

Thank you. I understand that "it is advisable" to follow the middle way, however, the question was specifically about the harsh language: fool and wicked. Why would following different lenient approaches (backed by renowned rabbis) be called wicked?

I believe I answered the question. Too many chumras can lead to kulas without careful consistency and only being lenient leads to an attitude that is not leshem shamayim

Did you mean to say that the use of those terms is (as usual) allegorical, the sages didn't imply "really evil like a sin" but "not optimal", or "dangerous practice"?

No I did not imply anything. I have given a straight answer.
